# Pymongo OperationFailure: Index with name: timestamp_1 already exists with different options

Tags: python, pymongo

I came across this problem when I tried some scraping code. I defined a class MongoCache to cache the html pages:

```
class MongoCache:
    def __init__(self, client=None, expires=timedelta(days=30)):
        self.client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017) if client is None else client
        self.db = self.client.cache
        self.db.webpage.create_index('timestamp1', expireAfterSeconds=expires.total_seconds())
```

when I build the object:

```
cache = MongoCache()
```

the failure information came out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\pythoncode\webscraping\mongo_cache.py", line 20, in __init__
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1958, in create_index
self.__create_index(keys, kwargs, session, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1860, in __create_index
session=session)
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 244, in _command
retryable_write=retryable_write)
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 579, in command
unacknowledged=unacknowledged)
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 150, in command
parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 155, in _check_command_response
  raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
  OperationFailure: Index with name: timestamp_1 already exists with different options
```

I tried some solutions from stackoverflow, but those are not for pymongo, and I cannot even use the method drop_index().
  I used win10, python2.7 on pycharm, and the MongoDB server version is 4.0.3.
  I have spent two days to figure out the problm, and gave up..

Comment: Can't you just use the mongo shell to execute `db.collection.dropIndex()`, especially since you have the database locally?

Comment: thanks Milan Velebit, your suggestion will be final step. but now, I just wondering why can't build the object, when I use the timestamp as the index. Is it the pymongo problem or others?

Answer (score 0):

Now, I tried the question again, and found that the problem may be in timestamp used for the index.
I define an object with no input parameter, everything's ok.

```
cache = MongoCache()
```

but, using the timestamp, it comes again:

```
cache = MongoCache(expires=timedelta())
```

The function for saving value for url is:

```
def __setitem__(self, url, result):
    record = {
        'result': Binary(zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(result))), 
        'timestamp': datetime.utcnow()}
    self.db.webpage.update({'_id': url}, {'$set': record}, upsert=True)
```